# access is denied while uploading file to tomcat server in java spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, tomcat

this is my html file: upload.html

```
<div ng-controller="fileUploadCtrl" class="allOrder">
<br /> <br />

<form ng-submit="uploadFile()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Item Image:</label>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" file-Model="myFile"
                id="image"> <br />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Image</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is my angular js controller: fileupload.js

```
adminApp.controller('fileUploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {
var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
var base = window.location.protocol;
var url = window.location.host;
if (!baseUrl) {
    baseUrl = base + "//" + url;
}
var basePathName = window.location.pathname;
var adminUrl = baseUrl + basePathName;

var productImageRestUrl = 'REST/files/uploadFile';

$scope.uploadFile = function () {
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
    var uploadUrl = adminUrl + productImageRestUrl;
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};
}]);
```

this is my java controller: FileUploadController.java

```
public class FileUploadController {

private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = System
        .getProperty("catalina.home") + "/kukus/images/";

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

/**
 * Upload single file using Spring Controller
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("File"+file);

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            System.out.println("Catalina base" +System.getProperty("catalina.base"));
            String rootPath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER;
            System.out.println("rootPath" +rootPath);
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            System.out.println("File Dir" +dir);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator);
            System.out.println("AbsolutePath" +dir.getAbsolutePath()+ "ServerFile" +serverFile.getAbsolutePath());
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            logger.info("Server File Location="
                    + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            return "You successfully uploaded file=";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

Every time i tried to upload an image it displays a message in message box.. c:/apachetomcat/kukus/images/tempFiles(Access is Denied)

and in console, output is - file is ()

I debugged the code it shows that it load data.jpg (whatever is the image file name) but it never saving to server location.

I tried to fix permissions of c drive- users and administrator as full control but it does effects the error.

Comment: Have you checked which filenames you effectively are using ? Print them and try to create them by hand

Comment: I think `File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);` denotes a directory, not a file.

Comment: @Marged I tried to give another path i.e. b:/uploads/.. to keep the image  just to test but still the error is Access is denied.... Is it related to spring security??

Comment: I am creating a file on server @JohannesJander I dont understand why I am getting Access is denied.

Comment: What Johannes meant: perhaps you are trying to write to a directory instead of a file. Because of this I asked for the output of the filenames

Comment: As @Marged tried to explain, your `serverfile` variable points to a directory, you cannot write data to a directory, you need to write to a file in the directory. Try `File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+"test");` and see if that works.

Comment: Hey thanks both of you, its my bad I am trying to upload an Image to a directory in server location..Whatever is uploading it is a file. Do you have any other solution for image?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator, file.getOriginalFilename());
```

It will save the file exactly the same with the uploaded one (name, extension).

I hope it helps you! :)